# MailChimp checkbox in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to add a checkbox to my WordPress comment form. Once this is clicked and the comment has been submitted, the mail address should be transferred to mailchimp.

I tried it with this code, funny thing is that the comment status is changed to "subscribed" but in MailChimp I can not see any new email address after my testing. Does anybody see whats missing here?

```
function custom_add_meta_settings($comment_id) {
  add_comment_meta(
    $comment_id,
    'mailchimp_subscribe',
    $_POST['mailchimp_subscribe'],
    true );
}
add_action ('comment_post', 'custom_add_meta_settings', 1);

function custom_subscription_add( $cid, $comment ) {
  $cid = (int) $cid;
  if ( !is_object($comment) )
    $comment = get_comment($cid);
  if ( $comment->comment_karma == 0 ) {
        $subscribe = get_comment_meta($cid, 'mailchimp_subscribe', true);
        if ( $subscribe == 'on' ) {
            $apikey   = '01d11fa0bhhg15d696985cbb8b812451-us10';
            $listid   = '1d9a4d2g6a';
            $endpoint   = 'https://us10.api.mailchimp.com/2.0/?output=php';
            $request   = array(
              'apikey' => $apikey,
              'id' => $listid,
              'email_address' => strtolower( $comment->comment_author_email ),
              'double_optin' => true,
              'merge_vars' => array(
                'NAME' => $comment->comment_author,
                'OPTIN_IP' => $comment->comment_author_IP,
              )
            );
            $result = wp_remote_post(
              $endpoint.'&method=listSubscribe',
              array( 'body' => json_encode($request) )
            );
            if ( !is_wp_error( $result ) ) {
                update_comment_meta($cid, 'mailchimp_subscribe', 'subscribed', 'on');
            }//if
        }//if
  }//if
}//function
add_action('comment_approved_','custom_subscription_add',10,1);
add_action('comment_post', 'custom_subscription_add', 60,1);

add_action( 'comment_form', 'custom_comment_form_fields' );
function custom_comment_form_fields( $fields ) {
    echo '<p class="comment-mailchimp-form"><input type="checkbox" name="mailchimp_subscribe" id="mailchimp_subscribe"/><label for="mailchimp_subscribe">Get my newsletter</label></p>';
}//function
```

Comment: Can you add an email address to MailChimp without the user confirming it?

Comment: Rob's point is probably what you're missing. MailChimp doesn't allow single optins, so you would also have to hack this in order to pass the email address to MC. Why aren't you using a plugin for this? A quick google search returns multiple options.